# How to Increase the Resolution of a Video from a Sequence of Photos?

Tags: resampling, video-processing, resolution, inverse-problem

I have a video filmed in a relatively low quality and resolution and a sequence of photos of higher quality taken of the same scene at the rate of about one image every two seconds or so. Could those photos be used to filter the video sequence to upscale it without loss to the sharpness?

Comment: Does the video pan or does it have a fixed viewpoint?

Comment: It is a car DVR video, so the image is constantly moving forward, although most of the objects wanted for the higher resolution are moving together. Yet I wanted a generic solution, if possible.

Comment: [Amped Software](http://ampedsoftware.com/samples) seems to make some great image improvement tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to solve a MAP problem of the up scaled video and using the High Resolution images as a prior.

Try looking at the articles - [Super Resolution MAP](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=super%20resolution%20MAP).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will take a look on it. Is there a tool that implements this (open source preferred)?

Comment: I am not sure. Have you tried looking in OpenCV?